# Can't create multiple striped disk volume in Azure VM

Tags: windows, azure

I created an Azure Medium instance Windows 2012 Server and I'm having a problem striping together multiple Azure data disks into a single volume using the Server Manager tool.

In Azure I provisioned the medium instance and then created 4 data disks of 60GB each. I then rdp'ed into the server and inside Server Manager under File and Storage Services\Volumes I saw in the Disks section my 4 data disks listed under the C:\ and D:\ drives that come with this instance. I initialized my 4 data disks (later I also tried NOT initializing them) but when I clicked on "Storage Pools" in the nav bar under the Virtual Disk section I only saw 1 of my data disks. 
I saw no way to add any of the other 3 data disks into my Storage Pool and then of course into the subsequent Virtual Disk. This problem limits me to just one data disk in my Virtual Disk. I have tried this many different times and the result is always the same.

Does anyone know what can be causing this or have steps to do the same thing I'm trying to do?

Thanks

If you're wondering why I'm trying to stripe these instead of using just 1 large data disk, this article explains the performance benefits of doing so:
http://blog.aditi.com/cloud/windows-azure-virtual-machines-lessons-learned/

Answer (score 1):

In my blog post I explain how to do this, although perhaps the level of detail you are looking for isn't there. Still, everyone that followed this post (it was a lab) was able to create the striped volume. The blog post is a complete lab; go down half way to see the section about the striped volume. Let me know if you have any questions.

http://geekswithblogs.net/hroggero/archive/2013/03/20/windows-azure-it-roadshow-lab-i.aspx

Thanks

Comment: Thank you for your response and link. I already tried using Disk Manager and that actually worked. But Server Manager and Storage Pools offer additional features and benefits over Disk Manager that is why I'm trying to create my striped disk this way. If only it would work.....

Answer (score 0):

I hit the same problem and some Googling revealed that this is a bug in Server Manager (sorry, can't find the link). The workaround is to use PowerShell to create the pool. These commands will create a new Storage Pool called "Storage" and assign all the available disks to it:

```
$spaces = (Get-StorageSubSystem | where {$_.Model -eq "Storage Spaces"}[0]).UniqueID
New-StoragePool -FriendlyName "Storage" -StorageSubSystemUniqueId $spaces -PhysicalDisks (Get-PhysicalDisk -CanPool $true)
```